# Meaning of prior density function

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, prior, posterior

When we estimate the posterior density function, we have the following equation:

$p(x|data) = \frac{P(data|x)*p(x)}{p(data)}$

Let us think that our prior is a continuous distribution, say normal. We are trying to get probability of success in a trial that is Binomial, that is p(x|data). Now, What exactly this multiplication means?

$P(data|x)*p(x)$ ?

P(data|x) - is 1 value, say 0.10, or 0.5, etc. On the other hand p(x) is the value of the continuous probability density function (normal here).
How can we multiply the value of pdf with P(data|x)?

P(data|x) is the concrete realization of the binomial trial with some given parameter x. According to Bayes rule p(x) should be the probability of the parameter, but p(x) is density! Without integration it has no sense. 
Could someone explain please?

Comment: You haven't applied Bayes' theorem when you merely multiply those two quantities.  You also seem to be very confused about discrete variables--although the *values* might be discrete, the *probabilities* of those values, as always, may be any real number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I fixed the question - i incorrectly formulated my thought (no descrete). I know what Bayes rule is - im just giving the part of the equation i dont understand - i dont understand how one can multiply P(data|x) by pdf in the numerator. Pdf in this case means sth like const*e^-(z^2)/2. P(data|x) assumes that we calculate binomial as x^k * (1-x)^n-k, where we have x fixed! But then we need to have p(x) - but first, its a distribution, second - prior pdf value at point x is not even probability. So yes, i'd like to understand what stated expression means :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ is a function that returns the density evaluated at its argument; so $p(x)$ is a number -- the value of the prior density evaluated at $x$.

Moving to a more typical statistics notation, where parameters are Greek letters and random variables/observations are Roman letters (presently handwaving the distinction between the latter two):

$p(\theta \mid y) = \frac{p(y \mid \theta) \cdot p(\theta)}{p(y)}$

For any given value of $\theta$, we can find $p(y|\theta)$ (the likelihood) and $p(\theta)$, and thereby take the product of those two numbers, obtaining the numerator and hence (up to the scaling factor in the denominator) the posterior evaluated at $\theta$.

Comment: Yes, we can obtain $p(θ)$ but it is not a probability. It is a number, value of the density function. While for example likelihood is a probability of some event happening with given parameter $\theta$, denominator is the probability as the integral evaluated over the domain of pdf. How can we multiply likelihood by something that is not probability?

Comment: Likelihood is not a probability either. Firstly the likelihood function (regarded as a function of $\theta$) doesn't integrate to 1, and secondly, even if you were regarding it as pdf for the sample (rather than a function of $\theta$), it would more typically be another density. You might perhaps argue that you are multiplying density by density to obtain something proportional to another density. (But I'd say that you could as well regard it as in effect multiplying two numbers to get another number.)... ctd

Comment: ctd ... but even if one of the terms actually *were* a probability, there's no rule that says you can't multiply a probability by some number that isn't a probability. All manner of valid calculations have the form of scaling a probability or scaling a density.

Comment: omg now its even more complicated :) So, we have 2 densities there in nominator? I need to think over your comment for a while...it kinda makes more sense i didnt think about it like that. So it kinda produces another density so range has nothing to do with the formula. it kind of matches each value of likelihood to each value pdf. Then if we integrate posterior over some range it should give us probability....i guess

Comment: The likelihood (regarded as a function of $\theta$) is not a density, but it is evaluated by computing one; it all depends on what you are looking at the first term as representing. However, note that $p(y,\theta) = p(y|\theta) p(\theta)$ so if you want to, you can regard the whole numerator as a single density -- a density in both $y$ and $\theta$. [Of course if you write the conditioning the other way $p(y,\theta) = p(\theta|y) p(y)$, and equate the two ways of writing the joint, then on dividing both sides by $p(y)$, we have Bayes theorem.]

Comment: Ok, back to step 1. Then if it is a probability, how can we multiply it with density? Bayes rule (basic form) says - Pr(A|B) = Pr(B|A)*Pr(A)/Pr(B). Pr(B) - is denominator, p(y). Likelihood is probability density and prior is density. because they are not integrated at all over any range. How is that possible? They are clearly not probabilities. So, multiplying them and getting pdf as output (p(theta|y)) - how is that possible? is there some proof of this?

Comment: I just outlined the entire proof in my previous comment. It's not quite clear to me what the difficulty is. Why would there by a problem with scaling a probability by the value of a density or a density by a probability?

Comment: In your last comment, does it mean that p(y, theta) is a joint distribution?

Comment: Yes, the joint distribution of $y$ and $\theta$. What's $p(x|y)$? why, it's $p(x,y)/p(y)$. If these sorts of calculations (such as multiplying or dividing densities and/or probabilities) bother you in some way, you ought to have run into the issue already.

Comment: Anyways, thank you for your time =) I will check your comments once again. I think you answered my question but im just not getting why. Need it to click.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48414/discussion-between-swim-s-and-glen-b).

Comment: If that ends up resolving your question, I'm happy to put together whatever parts addressed your uncertainty and paste into the answer. But right now I have to run some errands.

Comment: Yeah, would be nice of you =) I think joint distribution thingy was the thing i was actually missing (i can imagine it this way). Thanks =)